# Maximum size of data Bitcoin OP_RETURN tx can handle?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I was wondering, it's possible to do proof of existence with the blockchain. How many bytes can we put in the 'OUT' of the transaction? Is there a limit? If yes, how many?

Answer (score 3):

As intended by design, you can fit 80 bytes of arbitrary data in an OP_RETURN ( (I think originally proposed as 80, then set to 40, then set to 80, and it has been there for years.)

The script length is up to 83 bytes, but the first bytes are used up identifying the output as an OP_RETURN.

IIRC, the bytes are:

```
1: Output sequence number  
2: OP_RETURN code  
3: Number of bytes of data to follow (up to 80)  
4-83: data
```

You can theoretically put a large amount of data in an OP_RETURN, but only if you mine it yourself (easier if you happen to be a big mining pool.) This is because if you put more than 80 bytes of data in there, other nodes will not, by default, relay your transaction, so it will never reach a miner's node and thus never get into a block.

In the past, miners have included some rather long OP_RETURNS in blocks. There's an example of a long output from November of 2013 in transaction d29c9c0e8e4d2a9790922af73f0b8d51f0bd4bb19940d9cf910ead8fbe85bc9b in block 268060.

This site decodes the output of the OP_RETURN to human-readable text, read it and you'll see it's over 1000 characters:
https://bitcoinsays.com/d29c9c0e8e4d2a9790922af73f0b8d51f0bd4bb19940d9cf910ead8fbe85bc9b

Comment: Please note that the `up to 80` part is misleading: one data push can handle up to 75 bytes. Therefore OP_RETURNs with 76-to-80 bytes need special handling: encoded with OP_PUSHDATA1 with 1-byte length. More details: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116080/tx-with-op-return-with-77-bytes-of-data-refused-by-node/116083#comment132105_116083

Answer (score 2):

Using the `OP_RETURN` script you can put up to 80 bytes of data on the blockchain in exchange for paying a small transaction fee.  Some miners will let larger data through.

More details here: https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/transactions.html#null-data

Answer (score 2):

According above link https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/transactions.html#null-data, since Bitcoin Core 0.12.0 you can put up to 83 bytes.